# Dhanurveda original manuscript

Tags: scripture

Is there any original manuscript of [Dhanurveda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_martial_arts) or the original text which can be read online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read Dhanurveda from [sanskritdocuments.org](https://sanskritdocuments.org) in Sanskrit in [Devanagari](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/dhanurveda.html?lang=sa) and in the [transliterated form](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/dhanurveda.itx).

> **॥ धनुर्वेद ॥**
>   
>      अथ धनुर्वेदः
>   ईश्वरोक्ताद्धनुर्वेदाद्व्यासस्यापि सुभाषितात् ।
>   पदान्याकृष्य रचितो ग्रन्थः संक्षेपतो मया ॥ १॥

English translation for that is available  at [here](http://www.atarn.org/india/dhanurveda_eng.htm).

You can get authentic/original scripts with accent (Swara) from [vedicreserve](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/dhanur_veda.htm):

1. [Vasiṣhṭha Dhanur Veda](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/dhanur_veda/vasishtha_dhanur_veda.pdf):

   > [image]
2. [Śhiva Dhanur Veda of Maharshi Śhārṅgadhara](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/dhanur_veda/shiva_dhanur_veda.pdf) (Same as mentioned for sanskritdocuments.org)
3. [Nīti Prakāśhika of Maharshi Vaiśhampāyana](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/dhanur_veda/niti_prakashika.pdf)

   > [image]

Answer (score 0):

Dhanurveda is the science of warfare. It is an Upaveda, ascribed to Yajurveda. However, the original Dhanurveda treatise is lost. Only some smaller treatises on Dhanurveda are still available. These are as follows.

1. Aushanas Dhanurveda
2. [Vaasishtha Dhanurveda](https://ia904701.us.archive.org/20/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.382701/2015.382701.Vasistas-Dhanurveda_text.pdf)
3. Sadaashiva Dhanurveda (Veeracintaamani of Saarangadhara?)
4. Vishvaamitra Dhanurveda
5. Jamadagni Dhanurveda
6. Vaishampayana Dhanurveda (Neeti Prakashika?)
7. [Neeti Prakashika of Vaishampayana](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/nitiprakasika-of-vaisampayana-critical-edition-nai035/)
8. Veeramitrodaya
9. Samaraangana Sootradhaara
10. Dhanurveda Prakarnam (Veereshvareeyam) of Vikramaaditya
11. Kodandamandana
12. Kodandashaastra of Dileepabhoobhrita
13. Dhanurvidyaadipeekaa
14. Dhanurvidyaarambha Prayoga
15. Dhanurveda Cintaamani of Narsinha Bhatta
16. Ishaanasanhitaa
17. Kodanda-caturbhuja
18. Saara-sangraha
19. Sangraama-vidhi
20. Veeracintaamani of Saarangadhara

Only a few of these treatises are published. The rest are found only in manuscript form in important libraries, such as Darbaar Library, Nepal.

Apart from these texts, there are some other texts that are mentioned, but their manuscripts are not found yet. I have not included those names.

Reference -

[Dhanurveda - The Vedic Military Science by Dr Ravi Prakash Arya](https://www.amazon.in/Dhanurveda-Military-Ravi-Prakash-Arya/dp/8187710829/ref=sr_1_5?crid=27OMJK02OTQ2Q&keywords=dhanurveda&qid=1685539766&sprefix=dhanurved%2Caps%2C784&sr=8-5)

[Vasista's Dhanurveda Samhita by Purnima Ray (page 2)](https://ia904701.us.archive.org/20/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.382701/2015.382701.Vasistas-Dhanurveda_text.pdf)