# Are there any dedicated Scriptures, that explain these various weapons, vyuhs and war tactics in details?

Tags: mahabharata, weapon, war, vyuha

As I am reading through the Mahabharata (currently on the Drona Parva), I am truly amazed by the amount of details of war that are mentioned.

The types and varieties of weapons are mind-blowing, including the **normal weapons** like khand, shakti, **types of arrows** like Bhall, Tomar, **vehicle-mounted weapons** like Ratha Shakti and **divine weapons of gods** like Aindra-astra, Varun-astra, Brahma-astra just to name a very few.

The **Complexity of Vyuhas** (Battle formations) made in the war are staggering.

The information is too much and too vivid, but I would really love to read through detailed description of these things.

My Questions:

- Are there any dedicated Scriptures, that explain these various weapons, vyuhs and war tactics in details ?

Comment: one of the upanga (sub-branches) of Veda - DhanurVeda deals with this extensively

Comment: Hello. Can you add near English translation or Sanskrit form of weapons Khand Bhall, Tomar. I believe these are Hindi words. Many do not understand Hindi terminology and this may create confusion. Please add near English translation of those weapons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dhanurveda original manuscript](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12442/dhanurveda-original-manuscript)

Comment: @ram Thanks for referring to DhanurVeda, by reading an overview it seems like it only explains the basic weapons, Does it also explains the divine weapons and Vyuhs?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes, these are Hindi words, these are the names of those specific weapons, as I have read it only in Sanskrit and Hindi, I am not sure what could be their English translation, and this is exactly what I am looking for, the description of these weapons, how they looked and behaved.